# Draft-js: replace ContentBlock with a fragment

Tags: draftjs

I have reference on some ContentBlock(that not selected). How can i replace it with some fragment?

I have some fragment

```
const fragment = DraftPasteProcessor.processHTML(html);
```

And reference on block

```
const currentBlock = content.getBlockForKey(myKey);
```

How can i replace this block with a fragment. This block is not selected. I wan't to replace it and set cursor in the end of fragment.

I tried to use Modifier.replaceWithFragment, but this method works only with SelectedState.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this is to move the selection, then delete the fragment:

```
const fragment = DraftPasteProcessor.processHTML(html);
const myKey = 'some id'; // same as your code
const currentBlock = content.getBlockForKey(myKey);
const anchorOffset = currentBlock.getLength();
const selection = SelectionState.createEmpty(myKey).set('anchorOffset', anchorOffset);
Modifier.replaceWithFragment(content, selection, fragment);
```

This is a pretty common type of action to take with DraftJS. You'll notice on the [DraftJS docs](https://draftjs.org/docs/api-reference-selection-state.html#content) that it tells you to use the ImmutableJS functions (`set` in this case) to modify your selection as needed.